# Symfony dynamic database credentials

Tags: php, database, symfony, authentication, dynamic

Is it possible to make a input to set database user/password in Symfony at start-up of the application (like phpMyAdmin) ?

I want that my application do like this :

- Welcome page (only html, no database connection with just input for db username/password (like phpMyAdmin))
- User set username/password on inputs and click ok button => the values can be set into Request/post or Session in the controller by example
- Symfony connect database to all application and redirect user to 'app_index' route

Is it possible to do it with Symfony 5?

Here my controller action:

```php
public function database_login(Request $request, Connection $connection): Response
  {
    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $request->request->has('dbpass')) {
      $dbpass = $request->request->get('dbpass');
      $params = $connection->getParams();
      $params['password'] = $dbpass;

      $connection->__construct($params, $connection->getDriver(), $connection->getConfiguration(), $connection->getEventManager());
      $connection->connect();
      return $this->redirectToRoute('app_index');
    }
    return new Response(
      '<form method="post">
        <input type="password" name="dbpass">
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
      </form>'
    );
  }
```

The new connection work's fine but it lost after `redirecToRoute()` function.

Can you help me ?

Comment: HTTP is stateless. If you do not keep the DB login details somewhere, obviously whatever credentials the user entered are lost

Comment: Yes, i want to use Session or $config->setParameter instead of Request but i don't know how to use it to inject into doctrine for all controllers. The documentation dont explain how to use it :S

Comment: why don't you create login page and secure all routes with access_control unless /login ? like this all application will be secured and you'll be redirected to login automatically

Comment: i want make the user hability to connect to database with his own db credentials (like phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

@barbuslex, you can save variables to the session.

```
$request->getSession()->set('db_login', 'login');
$request->getSession()->set('db_password', 'password');
```

Also, to avoid passing these parameters manually every request, you could use EventListener, for example: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#request-events-checking-types

However, maybe you need another event, that is triggered earlier. Or play around with "priority" of listener.

Comment: Thanks! 
i know how to use session. I have see the method with wrapper_class on dbal obect but i don't have  access to Session/Request in ConnectionWrapper class :S
I will check with EventListener if i understand how it work's with Doctrine....

Comment: You need to get RequestStack in the Listener, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html.

Comment: Thanks you ! Is it possible to inject it in wrapper_class for database connection or not ?